# Spring Transaction doesn't Rollback at RuntimeException in @Transactional method

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-transactions

I have this DB configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany")
public class DBConfiguration {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource ds = new DataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/v2");
        ds.setUsername("java");
        ds.setPassword("mypass");
        ds.setInitialSize(5);
        ds.setMaxActive(10);
        ds.setMaxIdle(5);
        ds.setMinIdle(2);
        ds.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        ds.setLogAbandoned(true);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager txManager()
    {
        DataSourceTransactionManager tx= new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
        return tx;
    }

}
```

**QUESTION UPDATED**

I have some trouble to understand how @Transaction annotation works, please consider this scenario:

```
@Service
public class FirstService {
    @Transactional  //<--- this annotation seems to be mandatory for my rollback but I don't want it.
    public void test() throws Exception{
        secondService.insert();
    }
}

@Service
public class SecondService {
    @Transactional //<-- I would like to have only this method in transaction
    protected void insert() throws Exception{
        dao.insertEntity(new Entity()); //<<--- this is an SQL insert command
        throw new RuntimeException("Rollback test");
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
@RequestMapping("/test") @ResponseBody
    public void test() throws Exception{
        firstService.test();
    }
```

Dao:

```
public void insertEntity(Entity e) {
        getJdbcTemplate().update(SQL_INSERT,e.getCode(),e.getName());       
    }
```

This test WORKS, thrown exception could rollback the transaction.

**Why if I omit the @Transaction annotation on the firstService there is not rollback?**

Seems that from @Controller to @Service the txmanager looks for @Transaction annotation, from @Service to (another) @Service or @Component it doesn't look for it.

Comment: You can put you logs with debug and see if the @transactional attached to your spring transactionManager.

Comment: Post the code of the test, and the code of the DAO.

Comment: You are using InnoDB tables, right (or at least not MyISAM)?

Comment: Of course it is InnoDB :-)

Comment: I don't see transaction logs (with debug level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two error.

First error was that **I cannot nest two method (first not transactional, second transactional) in the same object** then I have to separate it in two objects (as you can see in updated question).

Second error was that **@Transaction annotation shuold be applied to public methods** not to private or protected.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }
```

Please update the spring version and maybe some logs or debug logs and see if there is an issue with Transaction